# Why doesn't my strtok() work for () specfically?

Tags: c

For example it prints '(night' despite tokenizing (), why does this happen?

```
char* word = strtok(&c, ",.;()");
  while(word!= NULL)
  {
    word = strtok(NULL, ",.;()");
    printf("%s ", &c);
  }
```

Comment: What is `c`?   If it’s a single char, using `strtok()` is wildly inappropriate.

Comment: What is `c`? Why are you applying `&` to `c`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code just prints `&c` on every iteration (whatever that is). You never print `word`, which is your next token. That's why you never see the results of your tokenization. If you want to see the tokens, you have to print `word`, not `c`.

On top of that it is completely unclear why you are applying `&` operator to your `c`. If `c` is a string pointer or a char array, that `&` there makes no sense at all.